# Dijit module scripts not being added properly; path incorrect

Tags: javascript, dojo

**Using Dojo 1.7.2**

Beginner to Dojo, trying to make a simple custom widget.

I have created a module with this definition, as per the tutorials:

```
define(['dojo/_base/declare', 'dijit/_Widget', 'dijit/_Templated', 'dojo/text!./templates/groupNode.html'], ...
```

And am calling it like so:

```
require(['modules/groupNode', 'dojo/domReady!'], ...
```

My dojoConfig looks like this:

```
var dojoConfig = {
    async: true,
    baseUrl: "./",
    packages: [
        { name: "dijit", location: "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.7.2/dijit" },
        { name: "dojo", location: "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.7.2/dojo" },
        { name: "modules", location: "modules" }
    ]
};
```

However, **after the page has loaded**, this module never finishes defining; when I examine the page source, I see that the script includes look like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="modules/groupNode.js">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="../dijit//_Widget.js">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="../dijit//_Templated.js">
```

Clearly, the `dijit` modules didn't compute the correct path, and aren't loading correctly.

Other custom modules which only use `dojo` modules work correctly.

There are **no errors** logged in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never used packages before within the [configuration](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/_base/config.html#dojo-config).  I have always used modulePaths.  Here is an example of configuring Dojo:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.7/dojo/dojo.js" 
  data-dojo-config="
    isDebug: true, 
    parseOnLoad: false,
    baseUrl: '/',
    modulePaths: {modules: 'modules'}
"></script>
```

So this means that in the root of the web directory, there exists a child directory named modules and that is where your custom javascript exists.

Comment: Yep, that works now. It seems like there are several ways to do any single thing in Dojo, each with their own little surprises... Thanks!!

Comment: To be clear: it was the `modulePaths` instead of `packages`. (baseUrl has to be './' because I'm running this from a local folder.)